# How to say “Fall asleep in 60 seconds” with 22 characters?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I’m a German app developer of the app “Pulse Breathing” that has recently had some success on the App Store and whose catch-phrase in the marketing strategy is: “Fall asleep in 60 seconds”. 
Now, the App Store has introduced some changes that make it harder to expose this marketing argument to the customers who visit my app page: until not too long ago, apps had a title (“Pulse Breathing”) and a subtitle (“Fall asleep in 60 seconds!”) that we’re displayed on the top of the page. 
Now, Apple has replaced the subtitle with the developer’s name, which makes it harder to market the app with this catchphrase.
So, I thought, why not put the subtitle into the title of the app as well? Turns out, the app title has a limit of 30 characters, which makes “Pulse - Fall asleep in 60 seconds” two or three characters too long. So I thought of alternatives. 
My first ideas (which I don‘t really like) were:

1. “Pulse - Fall asleep in 60 secs!”
2. “Pulse - Slumber in 60 seconds!“

The first one, I think, is too informal and takes away the credibility of a health app. Concerning the second one, I do like the idea of slumber, since it‘s practically impossible to fall asleep in 60 seconds, it’s just a catch-phrase; then again, I don’t know even know if it’s grammatically correct (would an English native say it like that?) and if it’s not this little bit too complex to really stand out. Fall asleep in 60 seconds, is simple, trivial and really stands out.

Do you have any ideas what else I could use? And how do you like my ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Fall asleep in 60 seconds" does the job perfectly but you also need the name of the app in there as well. Tricky.... You should change the number to 17 characters in the title  b/c *Pulse* has 5 characters

Comment: I make "Pulse - Fall asleep in 60 secs!" 31 characters (including spaces and punctuation). You need 3 more to get "ond" in there, I guess. Drop ! and spaces either side of the hyphen (and can you use a long hyphen or even a colon)?

Comment: "_Drop off_ is 3 characters shorter than "_fall asleep_", but more informal and unlikely to be understood by many non-native speakers of English. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drop-off

Comment: There is "doze" for fall asleep.

Comment: @Shoe I like that! 90% of the Downloads are from English speaking countries, so that would be okay; for the other main countries, I‘m using localized titles and subtitles!

Comment: @Shoe would "Drop off in 60 seconds" be OK? I'm undecided.

Comment: 60 seconds is one minute. How about " Pulse - Fall asleep in a minute" or Pulse - A minute to fall asleep"?

Comment: @Mari Lou A. I much prefer your "_Asleep in an instant_". _Drop off_ is problematic for non-native speakers, and anyway I would be worried about being sued if it took the user 61 seconds or more to fall asleep. An "instant" is a suitably vague alternative.

Comment: On the basis of the title I was expecting something about how boring it is refereeing a football match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Pulse* – Asleep in an instant

Excluding spaces, and the em-dash, the phrase uses exactly 22 characters.

*instant* (adj)
  Happening or coming immediately.
[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/instant)

Comment: +1. Great idea!

Comment: @AndyT do you think the majority of non-native speakers would understand the idiom? See Shoe's comment beneath the OP

Comment: Maybe not. Deleted my comment as it really wasn't constructive as a comment.

Comment: That‘s great, thank you! I think I‘m going to use this one! @Mari-LouA You‘re right that most of the non-native speakers would probably not understand it, but the App Store titles and subtitles can be localized. I guess I’m going to go with this one for the English-speaking countries and stay with the old titles for the other countries; for most of them, I have localized titles and descriptions anyways!

Comment: Which one are you referring to? The "drop off" idiom? Andy was talking about that. On the other hand, "Asleep in an instant" is very easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

You ask if a native speaker would say something "fall asleep in 60 seconds". That's grammatical, but it's a precise length of time which doesn't really have the meaning "really quickly" as "instant" does. If you are looking for a catchy slogan that does suggest that idea, you can say:

**Pulse–fall asleep in a heartbeat**

But it doesn't fit into the space allotted unless you change "heart" to ♥.